Deduce Tensor-Hom Adjunction for Different Base Rings.
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $N$ be an $A$-module and denote $\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,-)$ the $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor from the category of $A$-modules to itself. Let us say we define the functor of tensor product $-\otimes_A N$ as the left adjoint of the $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor, that is, there is a natural isomorphism $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(M\otimes_A N,P)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,P)).$$
for every $A$-modules $M$ and $P$. When I say "define" I mean to choose one of the (unique) adjoint up to natural isomorphism by Yoneda's Lemma.
There is a more general form of such adjunction, which I wish to deduce from the above adjunction. Now let $A$, $B$ be two commutative rings with identity and let $N$ be a fixed $(A,B)$-bimodule, that is, $N$ is a left $A$-module and a right $B$-module such that the multiplications are compatible.
Then for any $A$-module $M$, $M\otimes_A N$ is a $B$-module: for each $b\in B$ let $N\to N$ be the multiplication on the right by $b$, then this is an $A$-module homomorphism and it induces an $A$-module homomorphism $M\otimes_A N\to M\otimes_A N$. In the similar fashion, if $P$ is any $B$-module, $\operatorname{Hom}_B(N,P)$ is an $A$-module through the multiplication homomorphism $N\to N$ by $a\in A$.
With the above module structures bearing in mind, for any such $A$-module $M$ and $B$-module $P$, my goal is to show that there is a natural isomorphism $$\operatorname{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A N,P)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,\operatorname{Hom}_B(N,P))$$
for different base rings.

The natural isomorphism you want is a restriction to the corresponding submodules of the natural isomorphism you already have. Use naturality to establish this.
